Parallel Damping circuit for LC filter
I read this interesting article from TI about input filter (LC with parallel R-C damping) but I don't understand the expression for minimizing the peaking by evaluating Xi.

with :
Cd=n*C
Cd : Damping capacitor
C : Filter capacitor

Do you know how I can find this expression?

If I want for example to have a Xi of 1, what would be the value of n coefficient for the damping circuit ? From the expression, the value is near 1.6?! I probably miss something…


Thanks for your help
